# Using the value of a variable as an exit code from a script

Tags: bash, shell, exit, exit-status

I can find plenty of information about how to assign the exit code of a script to av variable, but I want to do the opposite: use the value of a variable (defined within a script) as the exit code of the script.

For example, I have a script that couunts the number of open files on a specific file system (plus a bunch of other stuff).  I want the exit code of the script to be the number of open files, so essentially:

```
#!/bin/bash

OPENFILES=`lsof /filesystem | wc -l`

exit $OPENFILES
```

So after the script exits, 'echo $?' will give me the value of $OPENFILES that was defined in the script.

I've tried various permutations of using quotes, parentheses, etc, but come up empty.  I feel like what I'm trying to do is either impossible, or so blindingly obvious that I'm overlooking it...

Comment: Should work other than you can only exit up to `255`.

Comment: That's my problem, then!  The values I'm working with are in the thousands when things are "working as expected", and reach a million just before everything goes all to hell (which is the reason for the exercise).  I suppose I can just write the value to a file and grab it from there...

Answer (score 3):

You can't really use the exit code for what you want, not least because the exit code is an integer between 0 and 255.  What behavior would you want if there were 783 open files?

Also, such usage is fundamentally broken in that you are positing an exit code other than zero *not* being an error condition, which is not remotely standards-compliant.

Comment: Thanks.  I suspected the answer was going to be the "so blindingly obvious..." one.  I completely forgot about the 255 max for exit codes.   As for the "standards-compliant" aspect, I really wasn't at all worried about that, as we're trying to hack together a solution to monitor an ongoing issue...one of those "sometime in the next fifteen minutes would be great, thanks" sort of things.  Hopefully whatever I come up with will be a very temporary solution (though we all know how that tends to go).

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to write to a file. Just have the script output the `wc` results

```
#!/bin/sh
lsof /filesystem | wc -l
```

and then capture the result with

```
openfiles=$(/path/to/openfiles.sh)
```

If your script is not more complicated than this, just add this to your ~/.bashrc

```
alias openfiles='lsof /filesystem | wc -l'
```

and then

```
n=$(openfiles); echo $n
```